Using emplace_back on an std::vector of a tuple
Suppose I have a struct, used later in a vector. I want to added an element to the vector using emplace_back without creating temporaries. I expected I would be able to use std::forward_as_tuple to pass two values as parameters for Foo. However, it fails to compile.
What's the right way to do this?
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    int a;
    float b;    
    Foo(int a, float b) : a(a), b(b) {}
};

std::vector<tuple<int, int, Foo>> vec;
vec.emplace_back(0, 1, std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2.0f));


Of course, I could do this:
vec.emplace_back(0, 1, Foo(1, 2.0f));

But this creates a temporary Foo which defeats the purpose of using emplace_back in the first place.

A side note: your proposed solution does not entirely defeat the purpose of emplace_back: you do save the creation of the tuple temporary. But I understand that idealy you would avoid the Foo one as well.

Can you change Foo to have a constructor taking std::tuple?

Foo is trivially copyable so it makes no sense to worry about the cost of making a temporary Foo. This question should probably be closed as a dupe of something related to the cost of trivially copyable types, unless you can come up with a meaningful example.

Else, you might create a tuple-like type with template conversion operator.

@JanSchultke
Foo is just placeholder for the sake of simpler example. The actual use case is class that's not trivially copyable

A way that you can do this  is to add a tuple constructor to Foo.
struct Foo {
    int a;
    float b;    
    Foo(int a, float b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    Foo(std::tuple<int, float> tup) : a(get<0>(tup)), b(get<1>(tup)) {}
};

If you were using std::pair, you could use the std::piecewise_construct_t constructor, however there isn't a variadic version of that.
std::vector<std::pair<int, Foo>> vec;
vec.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct, std::tuple(1), std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2.0f));


@463035818_is_not_an_ai yes, you could add combinations of tuple of references to the overload set, depending on what makes Foo heavyweight

ok, then my understanding was ok. In short (will delete the lenghty comment): You trade constructing the temporary Foo for constructing a temporary std::tuple<int,float>

Even if Foo is not trivially copyable, std::vector requires that Foo be at least movable. What you're attempting now is to save one extra move, which should not be necessary for almost every type.
But we're in the business of hacking the language, so you exploit casts to save that move
template<typename F>
struct initializer
{
    F f;
    template<typename T>
    operator T() &&
    {
        return std::forward<F>(f)(std::type_identity<T>{});
    }
};

template<typename F>
initializer(F&&) -> initializer<F>;

template<typename... Args>
auto initpack(Args&&... args)
{
    return initializer{[&](auto t) {
        using Ret = typename decltype(t)::type;
        return Ret{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }};
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, Foo>> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(0, 1, initpack(2, 3.f));
}

Live

Why do you consider this hacking the language? Do you mean that for most cases vec.emplace_back(0, 1, Foo(1, 2.0f)) should be fine?

@YakovDan It is arcane and convoluted. With the exception of some exceedingly weird types, moves should be enough, yes. The exceptional types are probably the culprit and should be rewritten anyways.
